# I am using laravel 5.3 , using MAMP as the server and my php version is 7.4.1

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

when I use this php artisan migrate  command, I got this error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
> could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravelcrud and t able_name = migrations)

> PDOException
> could not find driver

**my .env file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravelcrud
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql` will help you to fix this problem (just change the php version to the right version and then run it)
for example if you are using php 7.2 just run this

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have pdo_mysql, mysqli and mysqlnd driver. Run the following command in terminal:

```
php -m | grep mysql
```

If the said modules are not available, then

```
sudo apt install php7.4-mysql
```